# A representation of a $ C^{*} $-algebra.

Tags: operator-theory, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I have a quick question about the representation theory of $ C^{*} $-algebras.

A representation of a $ C^{*} $-algebra $ A $ is a $ * $-homomorphism $ \pi: A \to B(\mathcal{H}) $, where $ \mathcal{H} $ is a Hilbert space and $ B(\mathcal{H}) $ is the $ C^{*} $-algebra of all bounded linear operators on $ \mathcal{H} $.

> **Question.** Does such a $ * $-homomorphism exist all the time? If so, how do we know that such a $ * $-homomorphism always exists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The fact that such a $ * $-homomorphism exists is the statement of the [Gelfand-Naimark-Segal (GNS) Construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Naimark%E2%80%93Segal_construction).